# Flutter autocomplete widget optionsBuilder is displayed above the copy and cut tools

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I have this Autocomplete widget in flutter. I need a way to prevent the option list from appearing on top of the text copy and paste tools.

```
      Widget _build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider.value(
          value: _autoCompleteSearchBarCubit,
          child: BlocBuilder<AutoCompleteSearchBarCubit, AutoCompleteSearchBarState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Autocomplete<String>(
                optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                  return state.options;
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you need to customize it you need to add a custom design for the "optionsViewBuilder" with padding or margin.p

```
eg.
 optionsViewBuilder:
    (context, onSelected, options) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),//// Need to add padding here top widget
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Material(
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints:
          BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: options.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                int index) {
              final String option =
              options.elementAt(index);
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  onSelected(option);
                },
                child: Builder(builder:
                    (BuildContext context) {
                  final bool highlight =
                      AutocompleteHighlightedOption
                          .of(context) ==
                          index;
                  if (highlight) {
                    SchedulerBinding.instance
                        .addPostFrameCallback(
                            (Duration timeStamp) {
                          Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                              context,
                              alignment: 0.5);
                        });
                  }
                  return Container(
                    color: highlight
                        ? Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .focusColor
                        : null,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                        16.0),
                    child:
                    Text(option.toString()),
                  );
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the design does not allow me to change the padding, so that is not a viable solution for me.